# Differentiable sparsity measure

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, sparsity

I know that the sparsity of a matrix is the fraction of zero elements to the whole number of elements in a matrix. However, I wonder if there is a differentiable function or measure or approximation that does the same thing over a matrix: $F: R^{m\times n}\rightarrow R$, where F is a continuously differentiable sparsity function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Hoyer's sparsity measure.

[Originally](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume5/hoyer04a/hoyer04a.pdf) $\,$defined for a vector, it can easily be extended to a matrix
$$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}
\def\q{{\sqrt{mn}}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\H{{\cal H}}
\def\Jo{\| J \|_\o}\def\Jt{\| J \|_2}
\def\Xo{\| X \|_\o}\def\Xt{\| X \|_2}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\H = \frac{\Jt\cdot\Xt-\Xo}{\Jt\cdot\Xt-\Xt}
$$
where $J$ is the *all-ones* matrix with the same dimensions as $X\,$
and $\,\|X\|_\o$ is the Manhattan norm and $\,\|X\|_2$ is the Frobenius norm.

The range of values is $\;0\le\H\le\o.\;$
The lower bound is achieved for $X=J,\,$
and the upper bound occurs when $X$ has a **single** non-zero element. $\H$ is undefined when $X=0.$

Although the $\|X\|_\o$ term is not differentiable,
one can calculate the subgradient
$$
\grad{\H}{X} = \frac{\Xo\,X-\Xt^2\,J}{\Jt\cdot\Xt^3-\Xt^3 } 
$$
Hoyer's function has been used in the Lagrangian for Nonnegative Matrix Factorization (NMF) to induce sparsity in the matrix factors.
But as Hyperplane points out, including $\Xo$ in the Lagrangian will induce sparsity all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The $L^1$ norm, which is continuously differentiable almost everywhere (and even at points where it is non-differentiable, [subderivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative) exist) is often used to induce sparsity.

While it does not measure sparsity directly, solving constrained optimization problems like

$$ \min_x f(x) s.t. \|x\|_1 \le \beta
\qquad\text{or}\qquad \min_x f(x) + \lambda\|x\|_1
$$

Typically yield sparse solutions. The most famous applications begin the [LASSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) (sparse linear regression) and [compressed sensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_sensing).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the answer. I was wondering if one wants to use minimize the l1 norm of a matrix to induce sparsity, how is that possible if one does it in a supervised manner. I mean If I have a sparsity measure of a matrix, I can minimize the sparsity of the matrix via minimizing this: $||y-x||_1$ while y is the sparsity that I expect for the matrix in a cost function.